# How to display mean separation letters over grouped ggplot2 bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running some statistics, and need to display my results with mean separation letters over each bar. However, I am having a problem separating my mean separation indicator letters out over each bar.

Here is my data. Running this code should generate a data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c(1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             1,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             2,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             3,
                             4,
                             4,
                             4,
                             4,
                             4,
                             4,
                             4,
                             4,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5,
                             5),
                   habitat = c('woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'beach',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'prairie',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands',
                               'woodlands'),
                   species = c('skunk',
                               'fox',
                               'raccoon',
                               'gopher',
                               'raccoon',
                               'fox',
                               'skunk',
                               'gopher',
                               'skunk',
                               'fox',
                               'gopher',
                               'raccoon',
                               'gopher',
                               'skunk',
                               'raccoon',
                               'fox',
                               'raccoon',
                               'skunk',
                               'fox',
                               'gopher',
                               'gopher',
                               'fox',
                               'skunk',
                               'raccoon',
                               'raccoon',
                               'skunk',
                               'fox',
                               'gopher',
                               'gopher',
                               'fox',
                               'skunk',
                               'raccoon',
                               'gopher',
                               'skunk',
                               'raccoon',
                               'fox',
                               'skunk',
                               'fox',
                               'raccoon',
                               'gopher',
                               'skunk',
                               'gopher',
                               'raccoon',
                               'fox',
                               'skunk',
                               'gopher',
                               'fox',
                               'raccoon',
                               'skunk',
                               'gopher',
                               'raccoon',
                               'fox',
                               'fox',
                               'raccoon',
                               'gopher',
                               'skunk'),
                   response = c(321684201,
                                321684221,
                                321684211,
                                321684216,
                                321684201,
                                321684221,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684211,
                                321684221,
                                321684226,
                                321684206,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684211,
                                321684211,
                                321684226,
                                321684216,
                                321684221,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684211,
                                321684216,
                                321684226,
                                321684216,
                                321684216,
                                321684221,
                                321684201,
                                321684206,
                                321684216,
                                321684221,
                                321684211,
                                321684221,
                                321684206,
                                321684226,
                                321684226,
                                321684226,
                                321684211,
                                321684216,
                                321684206,
                                321684206,
                                321684211,
                                321684221,
                                321684216,
                                321684206,
                                321684171,
                                321684186,
                                321684181,
                                321684161,
                                321684226,
                                321684216,
                                321684221,
                                321684201))
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
# Open packages
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)
library(car)

# Convert columns to factors
data$group <- as.factor(data$group)
data$habitat <- as.factor(data$habitat)
data$species <- as.factor(data$species)

# Generate model and investigate significance
mod <- lmer(response ~ habitat * species + (1|group) + (1|group:habitat), data = data)
Anova(mod, type = ("II"))

# Interaction term isn't significant at the 0.05 level, but let's assume it is for this question.

# Separate means using the emmeans package
mod_means_cotr <- emmeans(mod, pairwise ~ 'habitat:species', 
                          adjust = 'tukey')
mod_means <- multcomp::cld(object = mod_means_cotr$emmeans, 
                           LETTERS = "letters")
mod_means$hsd <- c('bb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'aa',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb',
                   'abbb') # This is done to illustrate situations with long mean separator sequences
mod_means

# Generate the graph
ggplot(mod_means, aes(fill = species, x = habitat, y = emmean))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = "dodge", col = "black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean, ymax = emmean + SE), width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.6))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Species"))+
  xlab("Habitat")+ylab("Response")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size = 25),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20))+
  ggtitle("Graph Title")+
  geom_text(aes(label=hsd, y=emmean + SE), vjust = -0.9, size = 5)+
  ylim(0, 350000000)
```

Looking at the graph, the mean separations are all overlapping and not distinguishable. In addition, the bars are not separated by any spaces. **I would like to add spaces between the bars and wrap the long mean separators over each corresponding bar**; I'm assuming the `stringr` package would come in handy, but I'm not sure. How can I do these things?

Comment: It would help if you simplified your question to just the part that you have a question about. Here, provide the data for `mod_means` plugged into `ggplot()` and just the plotting code; that way users don't have to install packages and run models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error bars in your example don't show up because the SE is infintesimal compared to the bars themselves, so for the purposes of example I have multiplied them by 1,000,000. Essentially the problem seems to be that you haven't used `species` as a grouping variable in the text or error bar layers:

```r
# Generate the graph
ggplot(mod_means, aes(fill = species, x = habitat, y = emmean)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.6, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), 
           col = "black")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean - SE * 1e6, ymax = emmean + SE * 1e6, 
                    group = species), width = 0.3, 
                position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Species")) +
  xlab("Habitat")+ylab("Response")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 25),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
  ggtitle("Graph Title") +
  geom_text(aes(label = hsd, y = emmean + SE, group = species), vjust = -0.9, 
            size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  ylim(0, 350000000)
```

[image]